# Restrict UIDate View from scrolling to old date?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uidatepicker

How to restrict UIDate View from scrolling to old dates(past dates)?
UIDate View should show old dates but not able to select or scroll toward them like disabling them from scrolling to old dates. It should only scroll to new dates(upcoming dates).
i can't set it to minimum date because i have to take current date and it is not possible for my app to set it to minimum date.

If it is not possible with the given function. How can i make it custom or how can i programmatically ?

Answer (score 2):

If you're referring to a `UIDatePicker`, you can set the [`minimumDate`](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDatePicker_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDatePicker/minimumDate) property. I know you said you wanted to "show old dates" without being able to scroll towards them, but I don't think that's possible with the standard `UIDatePicker` class.

If it's absolutely necessary to implement this the way you've described you could always roll your own implementation and add that functionality.

Answer (score 1):

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *dpDob;

NSDate *localDate=[NSDate date];
dpDob.minimumDate = localDate ;
```

You can set it programmatically like this or from xib :)